# ternary operator in javascript when variable is empty

Tags: javascript, php, operator-keyword, ternary

I have used the ternary operator in php `$foo = get_field('foo') ?: null;` but I'm looking forn an equivalent in javascript. So far I've tried the `var foo = <?php echo $foo; ?> || null;`. But since `<?php echo $foo; ?>` in this case is null/empty the console is giving me the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ||` since  the variable is `var foo =  || null;`.

Is there another way of using ternary operators in javascript?

Comment: `var foo = ('<?php echo $foo; ?>') ? '<?php echo $foo; ?>' : null;` didn't work?

Comment: You JS should work, just output a "falsy" value from PHP when `$foo` is `null`.

Comment: @smarber the issue seems to be that the PHP code doesn't output anything, so the JS will still error.

Comment: Please notice the quotes around `<?php ... ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with ternary operator, but with PHP output to javascript. The safest way is:

```
var foo = <?php echo json_encode($foo); ?> || null ;
```

The `json_encode()` function makes sure that the variable is echoed in a form that JS understands.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a falsy value from php. Your code was almost correct. It was only missing the quotes around it.

```
var foo = '<?php echo $foo; ?>' || null;
console.log('foo', foo);   // null
```

This is because when $foo is empty, it will be `var foo = '' || null;`
and since `''` is falsy in Javascript, it will return null.